# inner join between Simple and Grouped products filter by Attributes of simple product (Magento)

Tags: magento

I am trying to show Grouped Products list based on attributes of its associated simple products. Right now i am doing like below

```
 - Create a collection of simple products and add attribute filters like color,brand etc., like below

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore())
        ->addAttributeToFilter($aname,$avalue)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter(ATTRIBUTE_CODE,ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_ID);
        (->addAttributeToFilter('color',5))

 - Obtain all resultant ids and get its parent ids using the below
      Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped')->getParentIdsByChild($productCollection->getAllIds());

 - Read the parent ids from above object and show the result in a custom grid that i created

 - Created a paging logic for parent ids and do paging in view file
```

This logic really consumes more time, is there any way that i can do all these in a single collection? may be inner join sort of method between simple and grouped products!

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Balan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends of attributes you want to filter with.
Magento already have prepared data for filtering grouped products by simple product attributes.
 It is stored in `catalog_product_index_eav`.
But these attributes should be marked as 'Filterable' in magento admin.

```
/** @var $productCollection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$productCollection->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore())
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'grouped');
$resource = Mage::getModel('core/resource');
$productCollection->getSelect()
    ->join(array('filter_eav' => $resource->getTableName('catalog/product_index_eav')),
        "e.entity_id = filter_eav.entity_id AND filter_eav.attribute_id = {$attributeId} AND value = {$valueId}",
        array(''));
```

Originally this table is used in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Attribute` function `applyFilterToCollection`. But it requires filter object as param.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for. It works well.
http://www.commerceextensions.com/filterable-grouped-products.html